# Distribute work load with job queue

Tags: load, message-queue, zeromq

I have an application that creates a number of jobs and I want to be able to process these jobs on several servers to distribute the load

Each job has a category and and all jobs in a category come in a special order, so if job j1 related to category A comes before job j2 also related to category A then j1 has to be processed before j2, but a job j3 related to category B can be processed in between.

I have two ideas of how to implement this:

1. Make one queue with all jobs and have several workers pulling from this queue. When a worker pulls a job related to category A, it has to lock jobs related to category A so no one else starts to process those jobs. It will then release the lock when it is done.
2. Have a queue for each category and then tell the workers which queue to pull from. If only one worker is responsible for a category queue you would not have to lock it. A worker could be responsible for many queues.

I like the idea with one queue and not having to specify a special queue for each worker, but I don't like the idea of having to implement some kind of semaphore for each category.

So far I have used Redis for queueing with great success, but I have started to look into zeromq which has more patterns that maybe could help me.

What would be the best way of doing this and what tools/libs can you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [Gearman](http://gearman.org):

> Gearman provides a generic application framework to farm out work to
>   other machines or processes that are better suited to do the work. It
>   allows you to do work in parallel, to load balance processing, and to
>   call functions between languages. It can be used in a variety of
>   applications, from high-availability web sites to the transport of
>   database replication events.

It allows you to distribute workload between servers (and, reading from case studies, looks to be good at that) and it also allows you to set the priority of tasks as high/low/normal, which you could use (if I understand your case correctly) to make sure that jobs are processed in the order they should be.